# Create a new class and load some copies of it into the view

Tags: iphone

Ok, i made a small application with a small ball bouncing on the screen. That was esay.
Now i'd like to have more than one ball... so i think the best way is to create a new class : the ball.

How can i do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encapsulate the information about the ball from your first app into variables, and create methods for any actions you think the ball performs.  This sounds a lot like an object-oriented design problem..perhaps you should take a look at an Object Oriented Programming guide, such as this one [OOP Guide](http://www.aonaware.com/OOP1.htm)

but if you are asking how to create a custom object class.. 
put this in your Ball.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Ball : NSObject {

    IBOutlet UIButton *button; //sample instance variable
}

@property  (retain) UIButton *button;
@end
```

then in your .m file:

```
#import "Ball.h"

@implementation Ball
@synthesize button;

-(void)dealloc
{
[button release];
[super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi Jesse, thank you very much for your answer.
I'll try to be more precise about my problem:

This "ball" should be associated to an image of a ball. I made this in Interface Builder, doing like this:
* Loaded a png file in Xcode
* Created an IBOutlet UIImageView named "ball"
* In Interface Builder, I have added a UIImageView on the main view and linked it to "ball".
* Added some methods
*Everything working fine.

But now, with the class, how can I do the same things?
I'd like to pick my png image and associate it to every instance of Ball, and have it on my view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thank you very much for your answer. I'll try to be more precise about my problem: This "ball" should be associated to an image of a ball. I made this in Interface Builder, doing like this:

- Loaded a png file in Xcode * Created an IBOutlet UIImageView named "ball"
- In Interface Builder, I have added a UIImageView on the main view and linked it to "ball".
- Added some methods
- Everything working fine.

But now, with the class, how can I do the same things? I'd like to pick my png image and associate it to every instance of Ball, and have it on my view. Thanks!